# Responsive rectangle with image fit to maximum size while keeping aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a responsive rectangle that has:

1. `height` that is 62% of `width`
2. `background: linear-gradient`
3. inside the rectangle is an image centered vertically and horizontally with a maximum size, all images have the same `width: 400px` but a different `height`

**What I have done before:**

1. for getting responsive rectangle I used this approach:

```css
.responsive-rectangle {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 450px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #0071B4, rgba(0, 113, 180, .8));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #0071B4, rgba(0, 113, 180, .8));
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #0071B4, rgba(0, 113, 180, .8));
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #0071B4, rgba(0, 113, 180, .8));
}
.responsive-rectangle:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 62%;
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive-rectangle"></div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/egrg4tbz/)

2. to align the image inside rectangle I have used `display: flex;` and `text-align:center;` with an `.img-wrapper`:

```css
.responsive-rectangle {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 450px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #0071B4, rgba(0, 113, 180, .8));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #0071B4, rgba(0, 113, 180, .8));
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #0071B4, rgba(0, 113, 180, .8));
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #0071B4, rgba(0, 113, 180, .8));
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}
.responsive-rectangle:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 62%;
}
.image-wrapper {
  margin: auto;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive-rectangle">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/zeek/image/upload/v1429436724/whiterryxmsuesx78joy9n9sa.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j1mtbkdh/)

This works perfect in case with image `400px x 220px`,
but with images that have a bigger `height` the correct aspect ratio is not used:

```css
.responsive-rectangle {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 450px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #0071B4, rgba(0, 113, 180, .8));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #0071B4, rgba(0, 113, 180, .8));
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #0071B4, rgba(0, 113, 180, .8));
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #0071B4, rgba(0, 113, 180, .8));
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}
.responsive-rectangle:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 62%;
}
.image-wrapper {
  margin: auto;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive-rectangle">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/zeek/image/upload/v1444889083/o67qntlwitbxnqz5qyjn.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmdqsqx1/)

Is there any approach that can solve my problem?

**Edit:**
Oh I forgot to note that `background-image` is not good solution because it does not support SEO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your final code is that the pseudo element used for keeping the aspect ratio is not actually performing its desired role. This is because `.responsive-rectangle` is set to `display: flex;`. To maintain the aspect ratio you can make the following modifications:

- Remove the `.responsive-rectangle:before` rule as the calculation can be done on `.image-wrapper` itself
- Remove `display: flex;` from `.responsive-rectangle`
- Remove the existing rules for `.image-wrapper` and replace them with:

  - `padding-top: 62%;` to ensure the correct aspect ratio is used
  - `position: relative;` to allow `img` to be positioned relative to `.image-wrapper`
  - `width: 100%;` to ensure it will fill the entire width of `.responsive-rectangle`
- Remove the existing rules for `img` and replace them with:

  - `bottom: 0;`, `left: 0;`, `margin: auto;`, `right: 0;` and `top: 0;` to allow the image to be centered in `.image-wrapper`
  - `position: absolute;` to position it relative to `.image-wrapper`
  - `max-height: 100%;` and `max-width: 100%;` to ensure the image does not exceed its natural `height` and `width` while keeping its aspect ratio

```css
.responsive-rectangle {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #0071B4, rgba(0, 113, 180, .8));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #0071B4, rgba(0, 113, 180, .8));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #0071B4, rgba(0, 113, 180, .8));
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #0071B4, rgba(0, 113, 180, .8));
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px;
    max-width: 450px;
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
}
.image-wrapper {
    padding-top: 62%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
img {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive-rectangle">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/zeek/image/upload/v1444889083/o67qntlwitbxnqz5qyjn.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="responsive-rectangle">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/zeek/image/upload/v1429436724/whiterryxmsuesx78joy9n9sa.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p23pgqp3/

Comment: Works perfect, thank you! I only changed `height:auto` and it works as expected

Answer (score 1):

I had to lay them out next to each other to see the issue. Here is a solution to your problem, just use the image as a background:

```
<div class="image-wrapper" style="background-image:url('https://res.cloudinary.com/zeek/image/upload/v1429436724/whiterryxmsuesx78joy9n9sa.png')"></div>
```

and then center it

```
.image-wrapper {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bmdqsqx1/1/

Comment: Oh I forgot to note that `background-image` is not good solution because it is not support SEO

Comment: If it's SEO you are concerned about just add some structured data to your HTML this has a vastly better effect on your ranking than an image tag (you can also add structured data pointing to the file itself) for example: http://jsfiddle.net/bmdqsqx1/2/

Comment: @ tripleb I understand what you say, but this trick is a little hacky in my point of view.